# Как удалить последнюю строку в базе данных msql ?

Tags: php

Как удалить последнюю строку в базе данных msql ?
Если можно с примером.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте от этого оттолкнуться: `SELECT * FROM 'table' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`
Эта запись должна вернуть последнюю строку.
Вам нужно не всю строку(все столбцы), а только id, значит далее так же подзапросом удалить.

```
DELETE FROM 'table' WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM 'table' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Удачи!

Answer (score 1):

Последняя строка - это которая последней добавлялась или которая последней редактировалась или строка с максимальным значением, например, поля id? В базах данных нет понятия последней строки, есть понятие последней транзакции.

**Обновление**

MySQL не разрешает удалять из таблицы строку, если из этой же таблицы в запросе идет выборка.
Вот так у меня работает:

```
DELETE FROM `test`
 WHERE id = (SELECT x.id
                         FROM (SELECT MAX(t.id) AS id 
                                 FROM `test` t) x)
```

Comment: с максимальным значением поля id

Comment: Delete from 'table_name' where id in (select max(id) from  'table_name')

Comment: Delete from 'massage' where id in (select max(id) from 'massage' limit 1)

phpMyAdmin  выдает ошибку :

Ошибка
SQL запрос: 


Delete from 'massage' where id in (select max(id) from 'massage' limit 1)
Ответ MySQL: 

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''massage' where id in (select max(id) from 'massage' limit 1)' at line 1

Comment: Id поставь в кавычки, должно помочь. Под руками не на чем проверить.

Comment: Поставил кавычки, результат тот же.

Comment: limit в выражении IN MYSQL не допускает)

Comment: Обновил первый ответ

Comment: 'massage' - это строка, а не имя таблицы, разве нет?